# AJAX URL append conflicting with stored jQuery .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, variables, reference

I've got a `document.ready` function that stores all of the data in preparation for a popover on `:hover`.

```
domReady( function() {
  $('.foo').each( function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var el_content = el.find('[data-content]');
    el.data( 'content-attr', { content: el_content, classes: el_classes } );
  } );
} );
```

Everything works fine by default, but when the URL is appended for AJAX sorting, I lose my `window` ref I suppose, because the following event handler returns `undefined` when accessing the data which is accessed without issue when the URL is not appended.  I'm aware that this must be a `window` reference issue in the event handler, can someone point me to the correct way to reference `window` so that that the jQuery object where data is stored on load is accessible to `.on( 'hover', function() { //do stuff });` while the URL is appended for AJAX?

```
$( window ).on( 'hover', '[rel="popover"]', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var this_content_data = el.data( 'content-attr' ).content;
    function() {
      // do stuff
    }
} );
```

Comment: Use `document` instead of `window`, since the [document object](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html) contains the DOM elements within the body, not the [window object](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of this particular issue, I realized the only way to do this was to store the data in a jQuery `.data` attribute on the initialization of the view for access by the function on `$(window).element.on( 'hover', ...){}`.